# Document Libraries Limits

Tags: document-library, document-center

I wasn't able to find this information...

My question is related to amount of document libraries that I can create on a Document Center web app. There is a limit?

Does anyone knows that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary difference between the Document Center and a Document Library are the templates they were created from - the Document Center from a Site Template and the Document Library is from a List Template.

As such, the limitations are governed by the Site itself which is constrained by content database limits (recommended < 200gb). In a practical scenario with optimal performance & storage for a Document Center, the results may vary based on the document check-in/check-out, versions & workflows, if any, are used. This post describes a Document Center example - [Enterprise content storage planning](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9994b57f-fef8-44e7-9bf9-ca620ce20734) (under section 'Large-scale authoring environment').

The number of document libraries under a site is contingent upon performance while viewing the list of libraries - I believe this limit is ~5000 items per view (default List View Threshold) for SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand the difference between DC and DL and I also know the 200gb limitation of content databases. What are you tell me is that as far 200gb can handle I can create many DL as I wish?

Comment: the only constraint I see is the ~200gb recommended limit (as stated by MSFT but this can be extended to ~1tb under certain conditions). There are other limits to the organization of the library (30m items per library, each doc item < 2gb, items per list view, etc).

Answer (score 1):

There are some recommendations related to capacity planning.
Start here:  http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc262787.aspx

Mark Kruger has a nice summary here:  
http://www.sharepointbloggers.com/2011/01/sharepoint-2010-limits-thresholds-and.html

Comment: Already read those links... None of them talks about the amount of document libraries that I can have, only information about content databases and document items... But thanks anyway.